# Setting the 'process environment' within the called nodejs script

Tags: node.js

How do I alter the environment, within the script itself, so that other succeeding code will ignore the status of the calling environment and will think the environment is what I set.

Comment: Do you mean code reading properties of `process.env`? You can easily override those. You can also change working directory by doing [process.chdir()](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'succeeding code'.

If you mean *'within the same Node process'*, it's easy:

```
// process.env.PATH = 'foobar';
require('child_process').exec('ls', function(err, result) {
  if (err)
    console.log('error', err);
  else
    console.log('ls', result);
});
```

Try this script with the first line commented out at first, and it'll work just fine. After that, remove the comments so PATH is overwritten by nonsense, and the `exec` will fail because it can't find the `ls` command in your PATH anymore.

If you mean *'for any following Node processes I might start after my first script'*, it's not  possible, since the parent process of those following processes is your shell and not your script. Child processes cannot change the environment of their parent processes.